# Postgres query that Update only changes

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I want to write a single query of UPDATE like I want to change only name of the person but my query was set

```
"""UPDATE person SET name='{name}', age={age} 
WHERE id={id}""".format(id=id,name=name,age=age)
```

but the parameter pass was `name='New name'` and `age=Null` was assign but it include to the parameter* `/?id=1&name=newname&age=null`

Anyone can help me get through this?

Comment: If you don't want to change the `age` column then remove `age=...` from your UPDATE statement

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help.

```
update_str = "name='{name}'"
if age:
    update_str += ',age={age}'

query = """UPDATE person SET {update_str} WHERE id={id}""".format(id=id, update_str=update_str)
```

Note: Never use this as this is prone to SQL injection. You have to pass parameter based on the ORM supports.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your ORM supports, you did not even bother telling us what it was. But if it is essential to sometimes update age but not at other times ( null passed) you can use the following:

```
update person 
   set name = parmerter_for_name
     , age  = coalesce(parameter_for_age, age)
 where id = parameter_for_id;
```

So for your ORM perhaps something like:

```
"""update person set name = '{name}', age  = coalesce('{age}', age)
 WHERE id={id}""".format(id=id,name=name,age=age)
```

Comment: Hi @Belayer Thanks its work for me. your such a  big help